# Is there a way to select two parts of an array and use both at the same time?

Tags: c#, arrays

Is there a way to select two parts of an array and use both at the same time? I am using this to mask some fields when a form is viewed. The first part for the SSN works, I just dont know how to do the second part. Any help is appreciated. :)

```
string SSN = fields.GetField("txt_SSN");
string[] strArray = SSN.Split('-');
if (strArray.Length <= 3)
{
    fields.SetField("txt_SSN", string.Format("XXX-XX-{0}", strArray[2]));
}
string BDATE = fields.GetField("txt_Date_Of_Birth");
string[] strArr = BDATE.Split('/');
if (strArr.Length <= 3)
{
    fields.SetField("txt_Date_Of_Birth", string.Format("{0}-{1}-XXXX", strArr[0]));
}
```

Comment: You should be more explicit, what are you trying to make happen in the second part?

Comment: Im sorry, I want the second part to display the birth date as ex. 11/12/XXXX. The top part displays as XXX-XX-2308. I also just realized i have to change the second part to slashes instead of dashes.                @EvanTrimboli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, just use it with the other item you're looking for. Say you're trying to use the first and second item in the array the following should work:

```
var BDATE = "08/12/2014";
string[] strArr = BDATE.Split('/');

fields.SetField("txt_Date_Of_Birth", 
    string.Format("{0}-{1}-XXXX", strArr[0], strArr[1]));
```

Given a date like 08/12/2014, this will output 08-12-XXXX.